# How to map OutputClaims with Json keys containing a dot (.) with Azure AD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need to develop a RESTful technical profile that is able to pass a JSON response such as:

```
{
   "somekey.withadot": "Some value"
}
```

My technical profile is as follows:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SomeId">
      <DisplayName>Some displayname</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Url</Item>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://someurl.com</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">identityProviderAccessToken</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="somekey" PartnerClaimType="somekey.withadot"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

However, Azure AD B2C tries parsing the JSON as a nested body due to their [dot notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#parse-a-nested-json-body). Has anybody come up with a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have been in contact with Azure. The engineers from the engineering team who have been investigating it did some additional testing and the conclusion was: if JSON parameter name contains a dot (example: somekey.withadot) then the claim cannot be passed regardless of whether ResoveJsonPathsInJsonTokens is set to true or false. The expectation is that the JSON property name does not contain a dot.

The team does not consider this a bug because the JSON property is not expected to contain a dot, but the team will submit this as a feature and also update the public document on ResoveJsonPathsInJsonTokens.

Update: It has been added as a feature request: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/23e6ae2b-4fdb-ec11-a81b-0022484ee92d

Answer (score 1):

Set `ResolveJsonPathsInJsonTokens` metadata item to `false`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#metadata

| Key | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ResolveJsonPathsInJsonTokens | No | Indicates whether the technical profile resolves JSON paths. Possible values: true, or false (default). Use this metadata to read data from a nested JSON element. In an OutputClaim, set the PartnerClaimType to the JSON path element you want to output. For example: firstName.localized, or data[0].to[0].email. |

Comment: For some reason, this does not work. First, it should work as stated originally since false is default value. Secondly, when explicitly stating that it should be false, it still doesn't manage to map the json values accordingly.