# Azure AD B2C - OpenIdConnect Claim with full URI

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a technical profile setup to connect to an OpenIdConnect IDP. It is connecting fine and getting a token, I want to retrieve one of the tokens and use it in my custom policies.

My output claim looks like the following:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" />
```

I've decoded the token that I've seen in the App Insights logs and I can see the upn token with value in there, but my policy fails when I try to use email saying it isn't found.
Sample snippet of the decoded token:

```
sub": "19804",    
"idp": "test.azure",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn": "email.address@email.com",
  "given_name": "Ben",
```

Other claims are being found fine that have more normal names like

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
```

I've seen [How to map OutputClaims with Json keys containing a dot (.) with Azure AD B2C Custom Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71400380/how-to-map-outputclaims-with-json-keys-containing-a-dot-with-azure-ad-b2c-cu) and https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/23e6ae2b-4fdb-ec11-a81b-0022484ee92d

Does that mean there's no way for me to retrieve that claim because it has dots in it?

*Edit
Hmm, one additional thing I'm noticing. In my App Insights logs I see it is getting two different tokens

1. My-OpenIdConnect (Jwt) https://jwt.ms
2. My-OpenIdConnect (Unspecified) https://jwt.ms
   Claims from the first token are being output but not from the second.

Answer (score 0):

So in my situation the URL claim name was not the issue. The IDP wasn't returning that UPN claim in the id_token, it was only in the access_token. It seems like it's not easy to get claims from the access_token (see [Retrieve custom claim from federating IdP access token in Azure AD B2C custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74081564/retrieve-custom-claim-from-federating-idp-access-token-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-po))

Luckily in my case I was able to get the IDP to add the claim to the id_token.